# Switching in react component doesn't render css

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have successfully implemented switching in react and it works as it should but when I refresh the page all the CSS for the switch routes I've done in the component disappears. The App.js routes have no problem and refreshing doesn't affect the styling on them. This only affects the component routes.[the image is before a refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0zxq.png)

[this is after the refresh[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhNZI.png)

App.js Routing

```js
<Router>
 <Switch>
   <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
   <Route path='/customerLogin' component={CustomerLogin} />
   <Route path='/customerSignup' component={CustomerRegister} />
   <Route path='/client' component={Client} />
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

Client.js Routing

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path={match.url} exact={true} component={Profile} />
  <Route path={`${match.url}/history`} exact={true} component={History} />
  <Route path={`${match.url}/policy`} exact={true} component={Policy} />
  <Route path={`${match.url}/feedback`} exact={true} component={Feedback} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Do you import your styles in App.js?

Comment: I import all the css in index.html in public

Comment: This really feels odd. Can you make some reproducible example, for example on codesandbox?

Comment: Lemme try. Once i do i'll post a link